# error LNK2019 when importing functions from a DLL

Tags: c++, dll

I'm learning how to build a DLL and call it from another project(I also want the DLL can be called not only by C/C++ but also by Python). Here is my code for building the DLL:

**callbacktesetDLL.h:**

```
#ifdef CALLBACKTESTDLL_EXPORTS
#define CALLBACKTESTDLL_API __declspec(dllexport)    
#else
#define CALLBACKTESTDLL_API __declspec(dllimport)
#endif

typedef int(CALLBACK *p)(char*);   

CALLBACKTESTDLL_API int __stdcall StrToInt(char*);      

CALLBACKTESTDLL_API char* __stdcall NumCompare(p FuncP, char*, int b);
```

**callbacktestDLL.cpp:**

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include "callbacktestDLL.h"
#include <stdlib.h>

CALLBACKTESTDLL_API int __stdcall StrToInt(char* StrInput)
{
    int IntResult;
    IntResult = atoi(StrInput);
    return IntResult;
}


CALLBACKTESTDLL_API char* __stdcall NumCompare(p FuncP, char* StrInput, int b)          
{
    int a = FuncP(StrInput);
    if (a>b)
    {
        return "a is bigger than b";
    }
    else
    {
        return "b is bigger than a";
    }
}
```

**And a Source.def file:**

```
LIBRARY

EXPORTS
StrToInt @1
NumCompare @2
```

With the code above, I got `callbacktestDLL.dll` and `callbacktestDLL.lib`. With **depends**, the functions' names in the DLL can be shown:
[image]

Now I want to call the functions in the DLL from another project:

**CallDLL.h:**

```
#pragma comment(lib,"callbacktestDLL.lib")

#include "targetver.h"

#include <stdio.h>
#include <tchar.h>

typedef int(*p)(char*);

extern "C" _declspec(dllimport) int StrToInt(char* InpuString);
extern "C" _declspec(dllimport) char* NumCompare(p FuncP, char*, int b);
```

**CallDLL.cpp:**

```
#include "stdafx.h"

int main()
{
    p FuncP_R = StrToInt;
    NumCompare(FuncP_R, "1234", 40);
    return 0;
}
```

However, when I run the project, it told me:`error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__StrToInt` and `error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__NumCompare`. I've already copy the `.lib` and `.dll` files under the CallDLL project's root folder. Why this happens? How can I solve it? Thank you for your attention.

Comment: Do you *link* with the library? And the DLL should be in the same directory as the executable.

Comment: Have you defined `CALLBACKTESTDLL_EXPORTS` for your DLLs? (And by the way, you only need to set the export declaration before the function declaration.)

Comment: Hi @andreee. All the codes are contained in the post. How to define `CALLBACKTESTDLL_EXPORTS`?

Comment: Hi @Someprogrammerdude Yes, I've added the `.lib` file in the project's property. `CallDll` is created as a win32 console application so no .exe file in it. I just put the `.dll` and `.lib` in the root folder of `CallDLL` project

Comment: If you have the command `dumpbin` available, you can also check with `dumpbin.exe /exports callbacktestDLL.lib` whether your DLL functions were successfully exported. You can also assure that names are exported the way you'd expect them to be.

Comment: @andreee You mean Project Properties -> Linker? I add the .lib file into it.

Comment: `extern "C"` prevents name mangling, while library still exports mangled names. That .def file is useless since it does not list correct (mangled) names.

Comment: For example, add `CALLBACKTESTDLL_EXPORTS` to _Your DLL Project Properties->C/C++->Preprocessor->Preprocessor Definitions_ to make sure the symbol is defined when creating the DLL (and thus the respective functions are exported). I have the feeling your DLL functions don't get exported. Plus, as @VTT correctly mentions, you export mangled names vs. importing demangled names.

Comment: Hi @VTT. Using depends, the names of the DLL's function can be shown. I've edited my post to show the names. I think the functions' names are OK.

Comment: Maybe `depends` shows demangled names?

Comment: @andreee I've checked the callbacktestdll project's Preprocessor Definitions. The `CALLBACKTESTDLL_EXPORTS` is already there. I think I'm exporting right function names according to what depends shown, which is updated in my post.

Comment: @VTT You mean `depends` shows the name writed in the `.def` file which are not the functions' real name?

Comment: @YQ.Wang: With depends, you need to check whether if you right-click on the exported names list, the option _"Undecorate C++ functions"_ is active to make sure there is no name mangling (which is the default).

Comment: Never mind, you can see by the symbol on the left ('C') that your functions were properly exported.

Comment: Not using the .h file in the client code as well is a Really Bad Idea.  You forgot the __stdcall attribute when you re-typed the function names.  That changes the decorated function name.  Never do this, use `#include "callbacktestDLL.h"` in the client code as well.  Not so obvious how this went wrong, if necessary double-check that you did not #define CALLBACKTESTDLL_EXPORTS in the client project.

Comment: @HansPassant You are right. But sometimes if a DLL's `.h` file can't be accessed, I have to use the .h file in the calling project.

Comment: Hmm, no, it can *always* be accessed.  Just like the .lib file and the .dll file.

Comment: @HansPassant I mean if someone gives me a DLL but keeps the .h file and .cpp file in secret, I can only access the DLL right?

Comment: The .h file is not a secret, it is *required* to properly use the DLL.  What other files were used to build the DLL, like a .cpp file, is not relevant to the client programmer.  So in the very unlikely case somebody does that be sure to throw away the DLL.  If you don't then you are liable to commit copyright infringement, that can turn out to be quite expensive.

Comment: @HansPassant Oh, I think I've understood your word. Thank you for your instruction.

Answer (score 0):

I finally made it. Here is the details:
The files that generate the DLL:

**callbacktestDLL.h:**

```
typedef int(CALLBACK *p)(char*);   

extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) int __stdcall StrToInt(char* InputString);     

extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) char* __stdcall NumCompare(p FuncP, char* InputString, int b);
```

**callbacktestDLL.cpp:**

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include "callbacktestDLL.h"
#include <stdlib.h>

extern "C" CALLBACKTESTDLL_API int __stdcall StrToInt(char* InputString)        
{
    int IntResult;
    IntResult = atoi(InputString);
    return IntResult;
}

extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) char* __stdcall NumCompare(p FuncP, char* InputString, int b)  
{
    int a = FuncP(InputString);
    if (a>b)
    {
        return "a is bigger than b\n";
    }
    else
    {
        return "b is bigger than a\n";
    }
}
```

Comparing to the former files in the post, I removed the `.def` file and added `extern "C"` ahead of each function declaration and definition. Then I generate a new .dll and .lib files and copy them to the `CallDLL` projects' root folder. I used `depends` to see the functions' names in the DLL:
[image]

I also changed the CallDLL's file like this:

**CallDLL.h:**

```
#pragma comment(lib,"callbacktestDLL")

#include "targetver.h"

#include <stdio.h>
#include <tchar.h>

typedef int(__stdcall *p)(char*); //same as typedef int(CALLBACK *p)(char*) in callbacktestDLL.h

extern "C" _declspec(dllimport) int __stdcall StrToInt(char* InputString); //exactly same as what's in callbacktestDLL.h apart from dllimport  
extern "C" _declspec(dllimport) char* __stdcall NumCompare(p FuncP, char* InputString, int b);  //exactly same as what's in callbacktestDLL.h apart from dllimport
```

**CallDLL.cpp:**

```
#include "stdafx.h"
    int main()
    {
        p FuncP_R;
        char* a = "1234";
        FuncP_R = StrToInt;
        printf(NumCompare(FuncP_R, a, 42));
        return 0;
    }
```

It worked as expected. I think one of the mistakes I made is missing `__stdcall` when importing. Maybe there are also mistakes about the name mangling. I'll keep testing it.

Comment: This approach might give you a DLL that you can use. But it has some draw backs. See my answer for details.

Answer (score 0):

You should always include the same header file to define a consistent interface. Creating different header files is error prone. The next change to the interface might make the interface incompatible.

There is a slight difference between the module that implements the functions to the module that uses the functions. The difference is the `__declspec(dllimport)` or `__declspec(dllexport)`. That's why the header files contains the

```
# ifdef CALLBACKTESTDLL_EXPORTS
```

Your module that implements the functions also export them. Therefore you must defined the symbols in the project settings. If you compile at the command line you have to add the `/D CALLBACKTESTDLL_EXPORT` to the compiler arguments.

BTW: If you have defined `CALLBACKTESTDLL_EXPORT` your macro `CALLBACKTESTDLL_API` contains the `__declspec(dllexport)`. This causes the linker to create the DLL export table. The `.DEF` is not necessary. You should remove it because.....  it defines the interface again (at a different level).

Comment: Thank you for telling me these details. Could you tell me when should I use `.DEF`? Another question, in my own answer, although the functions' names in the `CallDLL.h` are not the same as those in `depends`, why can I still import them?